# Clearing painted lines from HTML <canvas>

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to remove just the las line added to a `canvas`?

I want to have a vertical line following the mouse like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YsTWV/1/, but wanted to both keep the blue line under and remove the lines where the mouse has been...

Is this possible? or do I have to redraw the whole `canvas` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YsTWV/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<canvas>` operations cannot be inversed, as (subpixel-) antialiasing which may cause the draw operation to touch other pixels besides ones on the actual line.

Either do a full `<canvas>` repaint or partical `<canvas>` repaint.

Do not keep any kind of state on `<canvas>` object itself.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this... and if I do a partial repaint I supose it empties everything inside that square anyway? +1

Answer (score 1):

As @Mikko answered, `<canvas>` elements can't be removed.
You might want to consider using SVG if you need to modify the drawing.

```
<svg style="width:400px;height:300px; border:1px solid #ccf;" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
    <path d="M-1 0 l 0 300" style="stroke: grey"/>
    <path d="M0 0 L 400 300" style="stroke: blue"/>
</svg>
```

Javascript:

```
var svg = document.getElement('svg');
var grey = svg.children[0];
window.addEvent('mousemove', function (event) {
    grey.pathSegList.getItem(0).x = event.event.clientX;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzymek/R8KtC/

Comment: THis was also interesting, though in this case it doesn't work for me since I work with a plugin with a canvas were I need to add some features. But nice info +1!

Comment: You could still overlay an svg over a canvas and hava some drawing done using ctx and some with svg

Comment: That is also interesting! In my case I am extending a library/plugin, have svg and canvas same browser backwards compatibility?